# c function with array do not return value

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I wrote the following c-code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *read_from_file()
{

    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buf[22];
    char buf_old[sizeof(buf)];
    char candata_needed[4]; 
        ptr_file =fopen("/home/pi/probe.txt","r");
        if (!ptr_file){
            fclose(ptr_file);
            return 1;
        }
        if (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf), ptr_file)!=NULL){

            if(memcmp(buf, buf_old, sizeof(buf)))
            {
                memcpy(candata_needed, buf + 17, sizeof(buf));              
                memcpy(buf_old, buf, sizeof(buf));
            }
        }       
        fclose(ptr_file);    
   return (candata_needed);        
}    

int main()
{
        char *candata;
        int i;

    while(1){
        printf("stape 1\n");        
        candata=read_from_file()
        for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            candata[i] = *(candata + i);
        }
        printf("candata: %s\n", candata); 
    }
        free(candata);
        return 0;
}
```

The Function should read a file and store the content(the content is a 22 Hex number) in an Array. From the 22 hex number, i only need 4, so i stored the 4 hex number in a Array(candata_needed). 
So i want to get the stored 4 hex number from the function in a main-function a pointer. I tried with `malloc` but i became repeatedly an error  `double free or corruption (fasttop)`. With the pointer nothing appears. 
Can anybody help please?

Comment: `if(!ptr_file)fclose(ptr_file);` doesn't make sense. If the file wasn't opened, no need to close it. In fact, you're calling `fclose(0)` in that case; that certainly can't do anything useful!

Comment: The funny thing is that you *should* be using malloc or similar mechanisms, and you tag [tag:malloc], but you *don't* use it!

Comment: Note: `return` is not a function, but a statement. Don't put parentheses around a simple argument, this can result in subtle errors with typos.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a pointer to a local array. That local array goes out of scope once the function returns, leaving you with a pointer to an array that no longer exists. Attempting to use this pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

There are a few solutions:

- Make the array a global variable.
- Make the array `static`. That means its lifetime is extended to the lifetime of the program, and the pointer to it will still be valid after you return it.
- Allocate dynamically using `malloc`, and return that pointer. Don't forget to `free` the memory once you're done with it.
- Create the array in the calling function, and pass a pointer to it as an argument. Let the function fill in that array. If the function doesn't know the size (number of possible elements), you need to pass this as an argument too.

I personally recommend the last solution, but the "best" might differ depending on use-case. I really ***don't*** recommend the first solution, making it a global variable. I also don't like the second, making the variable a `static` variable, it's really no different from having a global variable IMO.

Comment: Upvoted: I prefer the final solution by a country mile.

Comment: Thank you i´l try again with malloc, it is the "best" way to deal with array in functions.

Comment: I can't resist, do forgive me: a problem with that approach is that if this function ever ends up in a library, then that library's `malloc` might use a different C runtime library than your `free`. Watch your computer slowly melt.

Answer (score 2):

`candata_needed` has automatic storage duration. It will go out of scope when the function ends. So don't attempt to return a pointer to it!

The behaviour on using the returned pointer is *undefined*.

One solution would be to pass a character buffer, along with its size, to `read_from_file`.

Answer (score 0):

@Joachim Pileborg: I´ve changed my code and i´m using now `malloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_from_file(char *result, int lenght_result)
{

    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buf[22];
    char buf_old[sizeof(buf)];
    char candata_needed[4]; 
    //while(1){
        ptr_file =fopen("/home/pi/probe.txt","r");
        if (!ptr_file){
            return 1;
        }
        if (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf), ptr_file)!=NULL){

            if(memcmp(buf, buf_old, sizeof(buf)))
            {

                memcpy(candata_needed, buf + 17, sizeof(buf));
                strncpy(result, candata_needed, lenght_result);

                memcpy(buf_old, buf, sizeof(buf));
            }
        }

        fclose(ptr_file); 
}


int main()
{
        int i;
        int size=4;
        char *candata = malloc(size);           
    while(1){

        read_from_file(candata, size);

        printf("candata: %s\n", candata); 

    }
    free(candata);        
    return 0;
```

The code works and i can get the data. Is this way ok or it´s not recomended?
My final goal is to send the data as output to another c proram. 
I´m new in C and it´s difficult for me to find the best way to resolve this problem.